# Is there a compressed representation of a set such that it can be determined if the intersection of 2 or more representations has a non-zero count?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, set, intersection

Let's say I have 2 very large sets of strings.   I'd like to make a very compressed representation of these sets so that comparing the two it can be determined if there are any set members in both the sets.   I'd like the representations to be constant space, or perhaps log N vs. the size of the set.

I don't care what the members are.   Or even the count.  Just a true/false for if there's an intersection or not.

My first thought was to have a bit array and toggle bits based on the set contents, like a bloom filter.   But how to check for intersection between two bit arrays?  I don't think this would work because the arrays would just be random bits.

Perhaps something like a radix tree?

I suspect an algorithm/data structure exists for this already.  There's compact probabilistic datastructures for set membership, I don't think this is too far a stretch.

Comment: If you sort both sets, comparing the two is an O(n) operation.

Comment: @MarkRansom it is also a space O(n) datastructure.   I want something that is at best a space O(c) data structure, like a bloom filter's bitmap.  Space O(log n) would be ok, too.   The idea is not to have the entire sets present.

Comment: I left a comment rather than an answer because I realized it didn't meet your ultimate criteria.  I hope someone has an answer for you, but my intuition says it won't be possible.

Comment: Thank you.  I was hoping there would be a clever way to do this, but maybe info theory says 'no'.  I guess I could get partly there with 32-bit hashes of the strings.

Comment: I thought about hashes, but just like a Bloom filter you have the problem of false positives - an intersection is indicated when it really doesn't exist.

Comment: You will need to define, for the context of *this* question, `very compressed`. *Radix tree*s/[*trie*s](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie#Compressing_tries) look a decent bet for *exact* result - I'd be surprised if an o(n) data structure existed.

Comment: (This [coinciding question about "co-compressing" multiple sets](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67097196) has me ask: what about an online variant - *keep* a data structure for multiple sets of sequences totalling *n* items in o(n) space that supports *intersection empty* in o(n) time?)

Answer (score 1):

There is in general no structure which takes less than O(n) space and can do set intersection queries. It's easy to see why: If you had that, you could recover each of the entries of the set by checking for intersections with sets, each containing one possible element. By the pigeonhole principle, this means that the representation must consume expected O(n) space.

Comment: The same reasoning applies to bloom filters. I believe the spirit of the question is that you're willing to accept the disjointness result being probabilistic.

Answer (score 0):

Theta datasketch looks intriguing.  It allows set operations like intersection and union on hashed representation of the sets.

https://datasketches.apache.org/docs/Theta/ThetaSketchFramework.html