# Online compression algorithms for multiple SETS?

Tags: algorithm, set, compression, on-the-fly

Algorithms like LZW and others compress data sequences.
What I'm looking is an algorithm that compress multiple Sets. if possible online algorithm.
For example :

```
 1,2,3,4,5
 2,8,7,5,4
 3,1,8,9,7
 2,4,5,8,7
```

becomes :

```
 Rule1 : 2,4,5
 Rule2: 8,7
 Rule3 : 3,1
 Rule4 : R1,R2

 R1,R3
 R1,R2
 R2,R3,9 
 R4
```

also we can have cases where Rules are hierarchical .. which will be better compression...
this is one example of compression .. i'm looking for online algorithm.

The hard thing is to do compression on the fly ... and be optimal i.e. maximize compression.

Comment: How big are these sets both in terms of max number of elements and range of values?

Comment: different, depending on scenario .. but i expect avg size 200, count 1e3 ... 10e6